# Child text - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a new text field, but I don't know how to get the text in the position I want. When trying to program, it stays in this position:

[image: problem]

but I want it to look like this, in this position:

[image: example]

This is the code:

```
body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, bottom: 15),
        height: 80,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 73, 158, 138),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(36),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(36),
          )
        ),
        child: Column(
          
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Olá, usuário",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 35,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "Olá, usuário",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 35,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](https://dartpad.dev/?id=471dbda96d7809a9fdfd0b2aef949087)

remove `height`
and set width as infinite to fill the parent using `width: double. Infinity`, Also set  Column to have

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```

Container should be first of child of Column

Comment: It fixed the problem, but do you know how to leave the second text out of the blue part?

Comment: check the updated demo. Its as per your need.